# Which companies allow advance, online booking of a bus ticket for travel from Istanbul to Sofia?

Tags: online-resources, buses, istanbul, sofia

I will travel from Istanbul to Sofia in February. Since the direct train route is no longer operational I'm looking to take a bus.

Which companies allow purchase of a ticket online in advance?

Comment: Have you tried looking for them online? Rome2Rio easily found this company https://www.metroturizm.com.tr/en/otobus-bileti/ISTANBUL_AND-SOFYA?date=25.01.2017&tw=0

Comment: I've found that company, they require a turkish cell phone number (which I don't have).

Comment: What's your source for "the direct train route" no longer being available? Seat61 claims there is indeed no direct connection by train, but the service still exists, and is temporarily and partially replaced by a bus connection. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: It's indeed partially replaced by a bus connection and has become very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

It may be difficult to buy tickets in Turkey because most booking sites require both a Turkish ID number and Turkish format phone number. At [busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-ankara-istanbul/r/sxp75e-sxk96f) we've solved this for domestic routes, I'll check into getting this international route.

- [HAS Turizm has a special booking site](http://eticket.hasturizm.net/Bulgaristan/) for their routes to "Bulgaristan" which seems to allow bookings for a maximum of about a month in advance but may not accept foriegn number formats.
- You can also book the [HAS Turizm bus on booking site Biletall](https://www.biletall.com) which generally works for foreigners though you may have problems entering your phone number.

Comment: Can you book by giving a fake ID number and phone number?